# jQuery setInterval from getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a script from one page and get it again after a certain period of time. But, the time varies each time. On the main page I have

```
function varcontent() {
    $.getScript("custom.php");
}
varcontent();
```

Then on the custom.php I have my script and

```
setInterval(varcontent, 20000);
```

at the end. Each time it may not be 20 seconds. It seems to work at first, but then the old ones are fired again too. I don't know how to get it out of this loop and they keep multiplying.

Comment: To have each script fire just once in the future after it is loaded, use `setTimeout()` rather than `setInterval()`.

Comment: `setInterval` itself loops the function for you, so you will have many calls to `setInterval`, hence your problem. Just use `setTimeout` and you will have just 1 loop (similar to recursive loop).

Comment: `setTimeout()` is to delay the function call whereas `setInterval()` is to repeat your function call for every time interval.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I thought since I wanted it to loop I should use `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout), not `setInterval`.  `setInterval` will keep invoking the callback (until you cancel it), whereas `setTimeout` will only invoke the callback once after the specified delay.

So in your `custom.php`, you should have instead:

```
setTimeout(varcontent, 20000);
```